# Supplying a variable string to model for Paperclip Imagemagik resizing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm using paperclip to upload some images which get resized. One of which I want to be cropped one of five ways... Anyway, I worked out what the strings to crop should all look like, by changing them by hand, but now i need to make that dynamic so that paperclip can crop based upon what the user wants...

The problem is that I'm getting

```
undefined local variable or method `params' for #<Class:0x00000105b228d8>
```

I feel pretty sure that this is because I'm attempting to bend rails to my will. Anyway, I think it's pretty clear what I'm trying to do... Just supply the crop_geometry_thumb variable to convert_options... Where should I actually be putting this logic that my model will be able to find it?

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
   if  params[:crop_geometry] == "bottom"
     crop_geometry_thumb = "-crop 200x100+0+100 -scale 100x100"
   elsif  params[:crop_geometry] == "top"
     crop_geometry_thumb = "-crop 200x100+0+0 -scale 100x100"
   elsif  params[:crop_geometry] == "left"
     crop_geometry_thumb = "-crop 100x200+0+100 -scale 100x100"
   elsif  params[:crop_geometry] == "right"
     crop_geometry_thumb = "-crop 100x200+100+0 -scale 100x100"
   else
     crop_geometry_thumb = "-scale 100x100"
   end

  belongs_to :piece
  has_attached_file :asset, :styles => {
    :large => ['700x700', :jpg], 
    :medium => ['300x300>', :jpg], 
    :thumb => ["200x200>", :jpg]},
    :convert_options => {:thumb => crop_geometry_thumb}, ### supply a string from above... FAIL :(
    :path => ":id/:style/:filename",
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
    :s3_permissions => :private,
    :url => ':s3_domain_url'
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the immediate problem is that request params (i.e. `params[:crop_geometry]`) are not accessible to your model, only to your controller + views.

In some cases (though it's never really a good idea), you can get around this MVC rule by passing params to your model as an argument for a method:

```
class FoosController < ApplicationController

  def action
     Foo.some_method(params)
  end
end

class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

  some_method(params)
     puts params[:crop_geometry]
  end
end
```

Instead, I'd recommend passing that param information into an instance variable defined in the model, and putting the conditional logic into a custom setter method, like so:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_reader :crop_geometry

  def crop_geometry=(crop_type)
    if  crop_type == "bottom"
     crop_string = "-crop 200x100+0+100 -scale 100x100"
    elsif  crop_type == "top"
      crop_geometry_thumb = "-crop 200x100+0+0 -scale 100x100"
    elsif  crop_type == "left"
      crop_geometry_thumb = "-crop 100x200+0+100 -scale 100x100"
    elsif  crop_type == "right"
      crop_geometry_thumb = "-crop 100x200+100+0 -scale 100x100"
    else
      crop_geometry_thumb = "-scale 100x100"
    end
    @crop_geometry = crop_geometry_thumb
  end
end
```

Note that you'll have to change your form so that it assigns 'top', 'bottom' or whatever to params[:asset][:crop_geometry].

Now, to dynamically set the crop_geometry, you'll need to use a lambda in the has_attached_file configuration--that way it'll be evaluated each time the configuration is accessed, not just when the model is initially loaded. Here you go:

```
has_attached_file :asset, :styles => lambda {|attachment|
    :large => ['700x700', :jpg], 
    :medium => ['300x300>', :jpg], 
    :thumb => ["200x200>", :jpg]},
    :convert_options => {:thumb => attachment.instance.crop_geometry},
    :path => ":id/:style/:filename",
    ...
}
```

Got that last part from https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip (look for "Dynamic Configuration").

Comment: Thanks Sam! I'm playing with it now and seeing if I can get it to work. I have to say I'm quite surprised to see someone I actually know in person on here.

Comment: yeah, I only noticed it was you halfway into answering the question. Small world!

Comment: So, I've spent a few hours on this since we last posted on here. The reason I haven't marked this as answered is that it's still not working for me. When I try to run the code with the lambda in place I get "undefined method `instance' for :all:Symbol". Which leads me to the question, what's the "instance" word all about in that lambda? I see it in the Paperclip examples, but it still doesn't make sense to me :/

Comment: Hey, so not exactly sure what the "instance" method is about--that's specific to paperclip. My guess is that paperclip yields to the lambda you pass in with an attachment class, which has an "instance" method that returns the particular instance you're dealing with on a given request. Anyhow, problem seems to be that paperclip is passing in ":all" instead of the object you're expecting. Updated the code above, I think it might work now!

Comment: I eventually decided to bail on this entire approach for something more flexible. Anyway, this does appear to be the answer, so I'm marking it as such. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm getting the "undefined method `instance' for :all:Symbol" error too. Has anybody got this working?

Comment: I had a similar issue. Instead of attachment.instance.crop_geometry I had to use attachment.crop_geometry