# get Jcrop coordinates to convert_options in Paperclip and Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lambda, paperclip, jcrop

I'm trying to take user hidden field parameters from Jcrop and crop an image before putting it on the database. I've found a few tutorials and questions but none address my exact problem.

This comes the closest. It looks like the poster was trying to use a single parameter from a selection. I have 4 integers. I didn't think that would matter so I assume it's the 'has_attached_file' part:

[Supplying a variable string to model for Paperclip Imagemagik resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815375/supplying-a-variable-string-to-model-for-paperclip-imagemagik-resizing)

That combined with this:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#dynamic-configuration

Here is what I have,

MODEL:

```
class Muse < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessor :w, :h, :x, :y

def get_coor 

 #turn parameters into class variables
  @w = self.w
  @h = self.h
  @x = self.x
  @y = self.y

  #build string for options
  cropper = "-crop #{@w.to_i}x#{@h.to_i}+#{@x.to_i}+#{@y.to_i} -resize 200x200"

  #return string of the convert options I want
  @get_coor = cropper

end

belongs_to :user
default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }

has_attached_file :muse_img, styles: lambda { |attachment| { original: (attachment.instance.get_coor) } }

validates_attachment :muse_img, presence: true,
                 content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpeg"] },
                 size: { in: 0..500.kilobytes }

end
```

I don't get errors. But it's acting like the get_coor method is calling nothing.

Before this I tried string interpolations directly on the convert_options, but it kept coming out as nil for all the coordinates. I'm new to Rails and Ruby so I'm still a little hazy on lambdas. Hopefully it's just a syntax error. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The solution seemed to be the order I put the params in params method. I had to put the coordinates first and then the image second. I found it here:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1533

I also changed the has_attached_file section but I don't know if that had anything to do with the problem. But here it is anyway.

```
has_attached_file :muse_img,
:styles => lambda { |attachment| 

    crop_convert_options = attachment.instance.get_coor

    {
        original: {
            convert_options: crop_convert_options
        }
    }
}
```